# Javascript for validating Multiline Text area's input characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiline text area which accepts 42 characters and if the user exceeds the limit and clicks on submit button, he will get a alert message like 'exceeded the limit so remove '***' characters. Below is the code which performs the same.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ok(maxchars) {
            if (document.ourform.box.value.length > maxchars) {
                alert('Too much data in the text box! Please remove ' +
                        (document.ourform.box.value.length - maxchars) + ' characters');
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/chkarea.pl"
              method="post" name="ourform" onsubmit="return ok(42)">
            Please enter data, at most 42 characters:<br/>
            <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30">
            </textarea>
            <br/><input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

But my problem is I should get the same alert message once I de-focus the control from the text box area instead of clicking on submit button. 
So Please help me for achieving it...!!
Thanks in advance...

**Additional requirement**: After getting the alert message and clicking on ok button,the extra characters should be deleted. Please help..

Comment: Do you wanna use jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using jQuery

```js
$(function(){
 $("#box").keypress(function(){
   if($(this).val().trim().length > $(this).data("limit") - 1) {
   alert("You have reached the limit");
    return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="ourform">
  Please enter data, at most 42 characters:<br/>
  <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30" data-limit="10" id="box"></textarea>
  <br/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Please try this.

Comment: Please help with additional requirement.

Comment: What is your additional requirement?

Comment: Additional requirement: After getting the alert message and clicking on ok button,the extra characters should be deleted. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the onchange or keyup event to bind this to the textarea.

First add an ID to your textarea. Then bind the event listener to it, and call your function.

```
document.getElementById("textAreaBox").addEventListener("keyup", ok(42));
```

Alernatively, you can use the `onpropertychange` event in HTML.

```
 <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30" onpropertychange="ok(42)">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Where should I add document.getElementById("textAreaBox").addEventListener("keyup", ok(42)); line in my code???

Comment: Right after the closing bracket for your `ok()` function.

Answer (score 0):

add this  onblur="ok(42)" or  onkeyup="ok(42)"  inside ur textarea

```
   <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30" onblur="ok(42)">
         </textarea>

     OR

   <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30" onkeyup="ok(42)">
        </textarea>
```

Comment: Please help with additional requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id/class for the textarea and go using simple 
JqueryEvents - Onblur or FocusOut event to trigger your function. 
--> https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Javascript blur event 
--> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can give '**maxlength**' attribute to your text area. Here is example.
It works.

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/chkarea.pl"
    method="post" name="ourform" onsubmit="return ok(42)">
    Please enter data, at most 42 characters:<br />
    <textarea name="box" rows="5" cols="30" maxlength="42">
        </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```